# Changing background colors affects unrelated views in another activity

Tags: java, android

I'm currently having a really weird issue in an Android app I'm developing.

The short story is that background colors I set programmatically in one Activity are appearing on completely unrelated views in another activity.

Basically, in one Activity I have a ListView in which the user can select or unselect any item by tapping it. When selected, an item is highlighted with an orange background. This background color is set programmatically via a ListAdapter.

The user may then navigate to a second Activity with a completely different layout in which every view is supposed to have a white background (this is set in the appropriate style/layout xml files). However, sometimes, the entire background of this second Activity turns the same orange color as the highlighted ListView items in the first Activity. Nowhere in the second Activity are background colors set programmatically, so I have no idea how they're changing color at all, let alone why they're turning orange.

If that's not weird enough, it only consistently happens on one device (a Droid Razr Maxx with Android 4.1.2) out of the 10-15 devices of varying manufacturers and Android versions I've tested the app on so far. Other than on that Razr, I've only seen it happen once on one other device. And even on that one, after selecting/unselecting different ListView items and going back and forth between the Activities a couple times, the issue disappeared and I couldn't reproduce it again.

Anybody have an idea what might be going on?

Comment: Did you initialize background of the second activity to white or some other color?

Comment: Yes, white. The second activity's layout is made up of a LinearLayout with several sub views inside it. The background color of the main LinearLayout is set to white in styles.xml, and some of the sub views also have their backgrounds set to white in their layout xml files.

Comment: I will ask you post code, otherwise it is hard to figure out for me